# Find the location of installed cod file on blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry

I downloaded the times of india app on my simulator(9800).

It installed successfully.

I search the cod file on simulator folder  "C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry JDE 6.0.0\simulator".

But not found the cod file on that location. Where should we can find the cod file.

And  (below os 5) simulator 4.7.0(9630), 4.5.0(8310) hasn't app world. then how to download app on those simulator.

pls help me..

Comment: Have you clean and build your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you cannot find the cod file on the simulator. If you want to delete the app you have to run the clean.bat file, but finding the cod file is not possible

Comment: hi friend., thank u for information. and one thing, how to download app on 9630, or 8310. In this simulator no blackberry app world.

Comment: Well I haven't tried this yet but I guess you'll have to download first the App World on the simulator